# Bamboo build of SilverStripe with local variables

Tags: php, database, silverstripe, bamboo

I've got my build going in Bamboo and am setting up tests which needs access to a database. I have a different `_ss_environment.php` for my local / dev / production which defines what database to use (among other things).

I'm going to create access to a database for the tests to utilise however, where in Bamboo can I put this `_ss_environment.php` which would be unique for the CI server? I would think it could go `/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/` which is the builds working directory however is this a volatile area? Is the correct place for it? I'm OK for it to be shared with other builds if that helps.

Comment: One reasonable option is to put your build assets into an S3 bucket or a Git repository somewhere and pull them in each time a build is created. This way you can also manage them outside the actual Bamboo infrastructure, version them, etc.

Comment: @RobbieAverill all the assets are in Git repos and then pushed to an S3 for use by CodeDeploy however this one file is something I don't want versioned or deployed, it's specific attributes for the CI server.

Comment: Right. I treat CI containers as blank slates. This means you provision whatever you need, and pull in any dependencies you need to run your tests. The environment file is just another dependency. You could otherwise look at creating one on the fly with your build instructions or something similar? I have an application where the equivalent file is stored with a .build suffix in a dev folder of the code and the build insurrections just move it into place. Up to you